# Pie chart showing only labels and not data

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl

I tried to create a pie chart using openpyxl. The chart displays the labels correctly but no Pie. Also how do I change the size of the chart? I have about 28 labels and as you can see in the image below the created chart window is so small to show all 28 labels, I have to stretch the chart's window manually.

```
ws = wb.create_sheet(title="Tags Chart")

for idx, val in enumerate(label_list_for_col_header, start=1):
    ws.cell(row=idx , column=1).value = val

for idx, val in enumerate(final_count, start=1):
    ws.cell(row=idx , column=2).value = val


pie = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row= 1, max_row=ws.max_row)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row= 1 , max_row=ws.max_row)
pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=False)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = "Bibliography by Tags"
ws.add_chart(pie, "C1")
```

[image]

Comment: I just found the problem, the data were stored in Excel as stings not numbers. The line that has the problem is  ws.cell(row=q , column=2).value = str(z). When I changed the str(z) to int(z) it worked. Now, I only need how to resized the chart area.

Comment: [Size and position](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/charts/chart_layout.html#size-and-position)

Comment: Also, you should answer your own question if you found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data was stored as text not Numbers.  So I changed the str (z) to int (z)

Comment: You need to avoid unnecessary type conversions wherever possible. openpyxl will handle most of this for you. Your code will then be much easier to read and maintain.